# Move between Columns with Rng.Offset

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to scrape data with VBA-Excel.
I was following a tutorial online on how to do it. In the tutorial, the person uses `Rng.Offset` but fills data row-wise.
I'm trying to fill data column-wise. Here's what I've coded up so far. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong and how to do this?

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim col As Integer

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    Set Rng = Range("A3:C3")
    Set Row = Range(Rng.Offset(0, 1), Rng.Offset(0, 1).End(xlToRight))

    With ie
        .Visible = True

        For Each Row In Rng
            .navigate "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & Range(Row.Column & "3").Value
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

            Dim doc As HTMLDocument
            Set doc = ie.document
            While ie.readyState <> 4
            Wend
        Next Row

        ie.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

This throws an error:

> Method Range of object _Global failed

Comment: `Range(Row.Column & "3")` makes no sense. What did you intend to happen?

Comment: Cells(3, row.Column) ?

Comment: You have set row as its own range variable and then gone on to use it again in your For Each Loop.

Comment: In the tutorial, it was done as Range("A", Row.row).Value, so I thought I could modify it, but perhaps I was wrong.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgbSpWfXjVY

Comment: I am guessing it was Range("A" & Row.row).Value . That is A1 notation style where it is column then row. You can't then put the column number in the row position. With cells you can do Cells(row, column)